How to replace \r or \n in \r\n python2.7
How to replace \r or \n in \r\n in Python 2.7?
Input string = 'hello\r\n\n world\n \r\r\n\r\n'
Output string = 'hello\r\n\r\n world\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n'

Try: import re; re.sub(r'\r\n|\n|\r', '\r\n', text)

Does this answer your question? Replacing "\r\n" with "\n"

You do realize Python 2.7 passed its end of life more than four years ago? There are not even security updates any more.

Split the string with str.splitlines, which supports universal newlines: ''.join(map('{}\r\n'.format, s.splitlines()))

you can use str.replace() method .
I am not sure about your python version however...
Input_string = 'hello\r\n\n world\n \r\r\n\r\n'
Output_string = Input_string.replace('\n', '\r\n').replace('\r', '\r\n')


This won't work: "\n".replace('\n', '\r\n').replace('\r', '\r\n') results in "\r\n\n" instead of "\r\n" because the first replacement result end up used by the second one. Using a regex you can do replacements all-in-one and avoid this issue
